# Solving Differential Equation $y'=\cos(xy)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My question is about solving differential equation $y'=\cos(xy)$.
I tried to changing variable $u=xy$
\begin{align*}
u &= xy \\
\frac{du}{dx} &= y+ x\frac{dy}{dx}\\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= \frac{1}{x}\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{y}{x}\\
\end{align*}
then since $u=xy\to \frac{y}{x}=\frac{u}{x^2}$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x}\frac{du}{dx}-\frac{u}{x^2}-\cos(u)=\;0\\
\end{align*}
finally
\begin{align*}
x\,du-(u+x^2\cos(u))\,dx=0\\
\end{align*}
since this is not an Exact Differential Equation$($Because of the existence of $\cos(u))$, what is multiplicative "integrating" factor? Is this equation solvable or not?

Comment: Is $y$ a one variable function or a two variable function ?

Comment: Actually $y$ is a function of $x$ i.e. $y=y(x)$

Comment: What makes you think that a symbolic solution exists? Most ODE do not have such solutions. What you can tell with certainty is that $|y'|\le 1$ so that $|y(t)-y_0|\le|x-x_0|$. One can suspect and probably prove that the solution becomes asymptotically constant, possibly at $y_\infty=0$.

Comment: Have you tried looking for an IF? -- though, as someone as said, there is probably no simple closed form solution. To investigate an IF assume it is of the form $z=z(x,u).$ Then multiply the equation by this and apply the condition of equality of mixed partials. However, I doubt that you would obtain a PDE that is more easily solved. However, there's no harm trying.

Comment: @LutzLehmann we can say that the unique solution for $y'=\cos (xy) $ relative to any initial data $(x_0,y_0)$ is uniformly continuous, but how can we confirm $y$ is asymptotically constant (i.e, $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}y'=0$)?

Comment: @Riaz Because the the "stable equilibrium" curves $y=(\pi/2+2k\pi)/x$ will eventually catch any solution and become asymptotic. With raising $x$ the "force" towards these moving equilibria becomes larger, so that eventually any solution will follow one of these.

Comment: @LutzLehmann but these curves $y=(\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2x}$ doesn't satisfy the equation $y'=\cos(xy)$, right? and, how their interceptions makes trouble for Picard'-Lindelof theorem?

Comment: No, but these curves become flat enough for large $x$ that they become a boundary. I do not have a convincing argument, but graphing numerical solutions against these curves confirms the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$ \log ( y')= \log (\cos (xy)) $$
differentiate
$$ y''= -\sqrt{1-y^{'2}}(xy'+y)$$
Once again differentiate
$$y^{'''}\sqrt{1-y^{'2}}= xy''(1+y{'2})+y' (xy'+y+2+2 y^{'2})$$

May be no closed form solution. Numerical integration ignoring spurious solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $u=xy$ ,

Then $y=\dfrac{u}{x}$

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{u}{x^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}-\dfrac{u}{x^2}=\cos u$

$\dfrac{1}{x}\dfrac{du}{dx}=\dfrac{x^2\cos u+u}{x^2}$

$(x^2\cos u+u)\dfrac{dx}{du}=x$

Let $v=x^2$ ,

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=2x\dfrac{dx}{du}$

$\therefore\dfrac{(x^2\cos u+u)}{2x}\dfrac{dv}{du}=x$

$(x^2\cos u+u)\dfrac{dv}{du}=2x^2$

$(v\cos u+u)\dfrac{dv}{du}=2v$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $w=v+u\sec u$ ,

Then $v=w-u\sec u$

$\dfrac{dv}{du}=\dfrac{dw}{du}-(u\tan u+1)\sec u$

$\therefore(\cos u)w\left(\dfrac{dw}{du}-(u\tan u+1)\sec u\right)=2(w-u\sec u)$

$(\cos u)w\dfrac{dw}{du}-(u\tan u+1)w=2w-2u\sec u$

$(\cos u)w\dfrac{dw}{du}=(u\tan u+3)w-2u\sec u$

$w\dfrac{dw}{du}=(u\tan u\sec u+3\sec u)w-2u\sec^2u$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The right hand side of the equation contains $w$ so we can't apply integral on both sides $wdw=((u\tan u\sec u+3\sec u)w-2u\sec^2u)du$